# UIWebview crashing on IOS 7 but not on IOS 6

Tags: iphone, ios6, uiwebview, ios7, xcode5

I'm using Xcode 5 to make my app. When I run it on the simulator using IOS 6.1 everything works perfectly, but when I run the app on IOS 7 it crashes! Here is the crash log I'm getting from the webview:

```
`Incident Identifier: 01BCFB4C-E85B-488D-9855-4188D27566B1
CrashReporter Key:   cc047dce10a1cd20b4718dbf73ddc413162841fe
Hardware Model:      iPhone5,1
Process:             Widgets iphone [420]
Path:                /var/mobile/Applications/0D552E90-FF2C-4561-B012-0901359ED7A0/Widgets iphone.app/Widgets iphone
Identifier:          jeardev.Widgets-iphone
Version:             1.1 (1.1)
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2013-08-27 20:49:46.578 -0500
OS Version:          iOS 7.0 (11A4449d)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x000000f0
Triggered by Thread:  7

Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x382e3a84 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x382e387c mach_msg + 36
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2dccc55c __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 152
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2dccacc2 __CFRunLoopRun + 858
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2dc3553c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 520
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2dc3531e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
6   GraphicsServices                0x326c933e GSEventRunModal + 134
7   UIKit                           0x3024e7b0 UIApplicationMain + 1132
8   Widgets iphone                  0x00071fa2 main (main.m:16)
9   libdyld.dylib                   0x3823fab4 start + 0

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x382f6c7c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3835ae06 _pthread_wqthread + 306
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3835acc0 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x382f6c7c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3835ae06 _pthread_wqthread + 306
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3835acc0 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 3 name:  gputools.smt_poll.0x16580fd0
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x382f6550 __semwait_signal + 24
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x382674e8 nanosleep + 168
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x38267438 usleep + 48
3   GPUToolsCore                    0x0062b0bc smt_poll_thread_entry(void*) + 120
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3835cc5a _pthread_body + 138
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3835cbca _pthread_start + 98
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3835accc thread_start + 4

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x382e3838 kevent64 + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x382320d0 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 228
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3822c63e _dispatch_mgr_thread + 34

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x382f6c7c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3835ae06 _pthread_wqthread + 306
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3835acc0 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x382f6c7c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3835ae06 _pthread_wqthread + 306
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3835acc0 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 7 name:  WebThread
Thread 7 Crashed:
0   WebCore                         0x35ac9de8 WebCore::ApplicationCacheGroup::selectCache(WebCore::Frame*, WebCore::KURL const&) + 544
1   WebCore                         0x358d12b6 WebCore::HTMLHtmlElement::insertedByParser() + 90
2   WebCore                         0x358c9936 WebCore::HTMLConstructionSite::insertHTMLHtmlStartTagBeforeHTML(WebCore::AtomicHTMLToken*) + 318
3   WebCore                         0x3589f1b4 WebCore::HTMLTreeBuilder::processStartTag(WebCore::AtomicHTMLToken*) + 2472
4   WebCore                         0x3589e76e WebCore::HTMLTreeBuilder::processToken(WebCore::AtomicHTMLToken*) + 86
5   WebCore                         0x3589e552 WebCore::HTMLTreeBuilder::constructTree(WebCore::AtomicHTMLToken*) + 30
6   WebCore                         0x3589e038 WebCore::HTMLDocumentParser::constructTreeFromHTMLToken(WebCore::HTMLToken&) + 96
7   WebCore                         0x358910f0 WebCore::HTMLDocumentParser::pumpTokenizer(WebCore::HTMLDocumentParser::SynchronousMode) + 248
8   WebCore                         0x3590234e WebCore::HTMLDocumentParser::append(WTF::PassRefPtr<WTF::StringImpl>) + 290
9   WebCore                         0x35901872 WebCore::DecodedDataDocumentParser::appendBytes(WebCore::DocumentWriter*, char const*, unsigned long) + 70
10  WebCore                         0x358bdae4 WebCore::DocumentLoader::commitData(char const*, unsigned long) + 32
11  WebKit                          0x362c366e -[WebHTMLRepresentation receivedData:withDataSource:] + 178
12  WebKit                          0x362c3508 -[WebDataSource(WebInternal) _receivedData:] + 132
13  WebKit                          0x362c3464 WebFrameLoaderClient::committedLoad(WebCore::DocumentLoader*, char const*, int) + 96
14  WebCore                         0x358f9240 WebCore::DocumentLoader::commitLoad(char const*, int) + 96
15  WebCore                         0x358f9198 WebCore::DocumentLoader::dataReceived(WebCore::CachedResource*, char const*, int) + 492
16  WebCore                         0x358f79b0 WebCore::DocumentLoader::continueAfterContentPolicy(WebCore::PolicyAction) + 760
17  WebCore                         0x358f6fde WebCore::DocumentLoader::responseReceived(WebCore::CachedResource*, WebCore::ResourceResponse const&) + 650
18  WebCore                         0x35b73a1a WebCore::DocumentLoader::handleSubstituteDataLoadNow(WebCore::Timer<WebCore::DocumentLoader>*) + 322
19  WebCore                         0x3581d2d4 WebCore::ThreadTimers::sharedTimerFiredInternal() + 132
20  WebCore                         0x3581d226 WebCore::timerFired(__CFRunLoopTimer*, void*) + 22
21  CoreFoundation                  0x2dccce84 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 12
22  CoreFoundation                  0x2dccca9e __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 790
23  CoreFoundation                  0x2dccae26 __CFRunLoopRun + 1214
24  CoreFoundation                  0x2dc3553c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 520
25  CoreFoundation                  0x2dc3531e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
26  WebCore                         0x358abf68 RunWebThread(void*) + 416
27  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3835cc5a _pthread_body + 138
28  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3835cbca _pthread_start + 98
29  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3835accc thread_start + 4

Thread 8 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x382e3a84 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x382e387c mach_msg + 36
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2dccc55c __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 152
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2dccac7c __CFRunLoopRun + 788
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2dc3553c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 520
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2dc3531e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
6   Foundation                      0x2e6519bc +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 316
7   Foundation                      0x2e6c72b2 __NSThread__main__ + 1058
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3835cc5a _pthread_body + 138
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3835cbca _pthread_start + 98
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3835accc thread_start + 4

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x382e3a84 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x382e387c mach_msg + 36
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2dccc55c __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 152
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2dccac7c __CFRunLoopRun + 788
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2dc3553c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 520
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2dc3531e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
6   libAVFAudio.dylib               0x2cc125ae GenericRunLoopThread::Entry(void*) + 126
7   libAVFAudio.dylib               0x2cc05f44 CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*) + 176
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3835cc5a _pthread_body + 138
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3835cbca _pthread_start + 98
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3835accc thread_start + 4

Thread 10 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x382f6440 select$DARWIN_EXTSN + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x2dcd045a __CFSocketManager + 478
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3835cc5a _pthread_body + 138
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3835cbca _pthread_start + 98
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3835accc thread_start + 4

Thread 11 name:  JavaScriptCore::BlockFree
Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x382f5f38 __psynch_cvwait + 24
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3835c262 _pthread_cond_wait + 538
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3835d03c pthread_cond_wait + 36
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x2ec3a408 JSC::BlockAllocator::blockFreeingThreadMain() + 204
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x2ec37a70 WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 12
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3835cc5a _pthread_body + 138
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3835cbca _pthread_start + 98
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3835accc thread_start + 4

Thread 12 name:  JavaScriptCore::Marking
Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x382f5f38 __psynch_cvwait + 24
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3835c262 _pthread_cond_wait + 538
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3835d03c pthread_cond_wait + 36
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x2edd8af2 JSC::GCThread::waitForNextPhase() + 74
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x2edd8b4c JSC::GCThread::gcThreadMain() + 48
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x2ec37a70 WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 12
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3835cc5a _pthread_body + 138
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3835cbca _pthread_start + 98
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3835accc thread_start + 4

Thread 13 name:  WebCore: CFNetwork Loader
Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x382e3a84 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x382e387c mach_msg + 36
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2dccc55c __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 152
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2dccac7c __CFRunLoopRun + 788
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2dc3553c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 520
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2dc3531e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
6   WebCore                         0x358f512a WebCore::runLoaderThread(void*) + 250
7   JavaScriptCore                  0x2ec37a70 WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 12
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3835cc5a _pthread_body + 138
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3835cbca _pthread_start + 98
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3835accc thread_start + 4

Thread 14:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x382f6c7c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3835ae06 _pthread_wqthread + 306
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3835acc0 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 7 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000008      r2: 0x9b81ac40      r3: 0x00000021
    r4: 0x00000000    r5: 0x0367daf0      r6: 0x04cf6750      r7: 0x031b4818
    r8: 0x0309f040    r9: 0x00000035     r10: 0x0309f000     r11: 0x04b2d000
    ip: 0x39d5d5cc    sp: 0x031b477c      lr: 0x35ac9de5      pc: 0x35ac9de8
  cpsr: 0x00000030
```

`
It is particularly crashing "Thread 5 Webthread" Sometimes Thread 8
Any feedback is appreciated :)

Comment: have you tried different URL to isolate the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem, @Jake Lin's suggestion was right it was the link. I was trying to connect to twitter and I was using the URL: http://mobile.twitter.com/account and I tried changing it to: https://mobile.twitter.com/account where I added the "s" in the http. Very strange problem but that seemed to fix it.

Comment: Good spot. Still looks like a hideous iOS bug. Please submit it as a bug report to Apple, even if you don't know why https made a difference :)